# How do I create a 'notify me of followup comments via e-mail' button in Django?

Tags: python, django, email, comments, notifications

I want to create a check box that my users (either login or anonymous users) can click that sends an email when a new comment is added to a post. As a side note I would also like to send an email to the Author of the post too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `django.contrib.comments.signals.comment_was_posted` signal. For an example, see http://timothyfletcher.com/blog/django-comment-email-notifications/